# Deserialize an object like Value<T> with gson

Tags: java, generics, gson

It seams to be impossible to deserialize a json string to a type with a type parameter.

I want to write a function like that:

```
public <T> Value<T> getValue (json, Class<T> clazz) {

    // THE PROBLEM: T becomes Object so the resulting
    // Value will hold an Object as value
    Type type = new TypeToken<Value<T>>() {}.getType();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

An Expample is:

```
Value<User> value = new Value<User>(
        new User("Max", "Hu", new Address("5th Av.","NY")), "infos");

// Works fine
String json gson.toJson(value, new TypeToken<Value<User>>() {}.getType())
// dosen't work
getValue(json, User.class)
```

The corresponding classes:

```
class Value<T> {
    T value;
    String someInfos;
}

class User {
    String name;
    String lastName;
    Address address;
}

class Address {
    String street;
    String city;
}
```

Do i miss something?

Comment: Your JSON example does not represent an array, yet you're trying to deserialize it into a `List`. It's therefore confusing what your intent is. Please supply a valid example of the initial JSON input.

Comment: Sorry, i spent to less time writing this question. Hope it got clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the issue with GSON would be, but most likely it is due to static (compile-time) nature of TypeToken, which prevents dynamic variation (partly due to Java Type Erasure).
But if you do not absolutely have to use GSON for this, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org) can support this use case easily.

You would need to construct parameterized JavaType (`TypeFactory.parametricType(Value.class, clazz)`), and give it as the type to bind to. Something like:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Value<User> user = mapper.readValue(json, mapper.getTypeFactory().parametericType(Value.class, User.class));
```

and you can encapsulate similar logic in a method. I use this for handling generic types of request/response beans (i.e. payload is generic; common pieces are in base type).